# Python os.path.isfile() never retrurns

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, operating-system, copy

i was wondering if this is a common Problem:

I myself wrote a Program which copys files (if found) from one place to another.  `The first call is os.path.isfile(wholepath+file)`
But this call never return something. Instead the Program stops. The Problem could be that there are 1 millions of files (multiple TB). In this case, is there another better solution?

The Program is now running for an hour and does not need much cpu (htop)

Comment: can you share a significant piece of your code?

Comment: import os, shutil
with open() as file:
    for line in file:
       if(os.path.isfile(file)):
          print('Here')
          //shutil.copyfile()


Here is never on console

Comment: please [edit] in your question, not in comments.

Comment: wait: ` if(os.path.isfile(file))` ??? on a file handle? this cannot be your code.

Answer (score 1):

`isfile()` returns True if path is an existing regular file.

try this one:

```
print [fle for fle in os.listdir(wholepath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(wholepath, fle))]
```

Note that your list will return as an empty list if your path consists of only folders and not files.